# Is there anything similar to {!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)} which we can use in LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, attachment, urlfor

I have attachment Id and I need the URL for that particular attachment. Right now In `visualforce` we have
`{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)}` to get the URL.

But In my `LWC` component I am constructing the URL programmatically like:

```
url = `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=${attachmentId}`
```

I want to avoid harcoding the first part of the string /servlet/servlet.FileDownload.. Is there anything similar in LWC that we can use to get the URL directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but... You could call [Url.getFileFieldURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm) in Apex to resolve the URL you need, then link to that dynamically in LWC.